# what expression should I use to output two metrics in grafana from prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, minikube, promql

I installed a test cluster using Minikube. Also I've installed Prometheus, Grafana & Loki using helm chart. I want to output two metrics, but I don't know how. First metric is half done, but for some reason, it is not output if you put the mount point "/", and I need the metric itself with it, which is needed:

1. Percentage of free disk space — mount point ‘/’, exclude tmpfs

   ```
    node_filesystem_avail_bytes{fstype!='tmpfs'} / node_filesystem_size_bytes{fstype!='tmpfs'} * 100
   ```
2. second metric: Number of API servers running. I don't know how to get it out.

Comment: Please share details how exactly did you set up your cluster, which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you configure Prometheus and Grafana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own
first metric they did not change it, since there is no such mountpoint /

second metric
count(kube_pod_info{pod=~".*apiserver.*",namespace=".."})